# Could not get Json data parse in asp mvc C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am new in asp.net MVC, i want to parse JSON data so i did some research how to do that and did it according that but could not getting result.

I am getting this error using try catch

> 'long' does not contain a definition for 'listDemo'

**Json Data:** stored in `var response`

```
{
    "RequestNo" : 232,
    "CardDetail" : {
        "Mobileno" : 98983232323,
        "Balance" : 0,
        "RemitLimitAvailable" : 2323
    },
    "listDemo" : {
        "TAG0" : {
            "Code" : 2323,
            "Name" : Demo,
            "Type" : Demo
        },
        "TAG1" : {
            "Code" : 424,
            "Name" : Demo,
            "Type" : Demo
        }
    },
    "Response" : SUCCESS,
    "Message" : REQUEST SUCCESSFULLY COMPLETED.,
    "Code" : 300
}
```

**C# Code:**

```
dynamic dataObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(response);
try
{
    string benCode = dataObj.listDemo.TAG0.Code;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    table += ex.Message;
}
```

Is there any way to get data ?

Answer (score 1):

> string benCode = dataObj.Beneficiary.TAG0.Code;

I don't spot any `Beneficiary` in your JSON ...

Use

```
int benCode = dataObj.listDemo.TAG0.Code;
```

*(listDemo.TAG0.Code also returns an integer not a string)*

Side note: Valid JSON example would be

```
{
    "RequestNo" : 232,
    "CardDetail" : {
        "Mobileno" : 98983232323,
        "Balance" : 0,
        "RemitLimitAvailable" : 2323
    },
    "listDemo" : {
        "TAG0" : {
            "Code" : 2323,
            "Name" : "Demo",
            "Type" : "Demo"
        },
        "TAG1" : {
            "Code" : 424,
            "Name" : "Demo",
            "Type" : "Demo"
        }
    },
    "Response" : "SUCCESS",
    "Message" : "REQUEST SUCCESSFULLY COMPLETED.",
    "Code" : 300
}
```

Comment: i did it but still has a same issue.

Comment: @ManishTiwari why do you change the original code you posted ?

Comment: @ManishTiwari ... and btw your error *'long' does not contain a definition for 'listDemo'* is not verifiable. So consider making a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)